# How can I plot the genealogy of a user created population?

Tags: plot, rstudio, genetics

I wrote a code to model the Wright-Fisher model of genetic drift. This means that an original population of N different individuals will have an infinite progeny population and then random selection determines the next generation. I would like to create a graph that can follow each individual line throughout these generations like in the figure below. [Here one particular ancestor's line is highlighted. Any sort of tracking of ancestor lines would be ideal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttBHZ.png)

Thanks! I have provided my code below:

```
 Simulates Wright-Fisher model for N different haploid individuals

N <- 10             # Number of individuals
gens <- 40          # Number of generations model will run
init.j <- 1:1:N     # Creates vector of initial population lines
p <- 1/N            # Frequency of each individual's alleles
                # note that two indiv may share same allele but are considered different 
p.vector <- rep(p,N) # creates vector of length N with the prob 1/N in each position
p.pick <- cumsum(p.vector)


j=matrix(init.j,N,gens+1)  #Creates matrix that will track each individual's     progeny line

for(i in 1:gens+1){  
  for(k in 1:N){
y = runif(1, min=0, max=1)
x <- p.pick - y
b <- min(x[which(x > 0,arr.ind = TRUE)]) 
j[k,i] = match(b,x)
  }
}  

J = apply(j, 2, sort) #Sorts each column to align ancestors with next generation which helps for visualization of genealogy
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a multitree:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree

Only thing I found was multiTree:

http://psycho3.uni-mannheim.de/Home/Research/Software/multiTree/

There was R code to interface with this:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20160285

But, seems like the package is not on CRAN and the website cited in the abstract no longer exists.